# Handle Button Click on server click runs repeatedly

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem in a HTML button click when handles in the server side; the procedure runs every click on any button on the page.

and that's my code:

```
 <button id="btnPrintWord" class="btn btn-small btn-info" title="Print Word " runat="server"> <i class="fa fa-file-word-o" style="padding-top: 3px;"></i></button>

<button id="btnPrint" style="background: #f72828d9;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" title="Print PDF" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" style="padding-top: 3px;"></i> </button>
```

and code behind:

```
Protected Sub exportToWord(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintWord.ServerClick
''''
''''''
''''''
End Sub
```

when click on the btnPrint the code of btnPrintWord rerun.

Comment: of course... btw. where is your `exportToWord` button? change `Protected Sub exportToWord` to `Protected Sub btnPrintWord`

Comment: @nelek I changed it , it give me the error there is already declared event btnPrintWord as HTML Button

Comment: point is, you don't have anywhere button `exportToWord` in yout html

Comment: You can use OnServerClick method, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_HtmlControls_HtmlButton_OnServerClick_System_EventArgs_

Comment: @nelek yes I know , that's the procedure name but this procedure handles the btnPrintWord Click

Comment: @FarhadMortezapour the same problem still

Comment: then provide more code

Comment: @nelek that's the code of btnPrint in the client side: $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
                var printContents = document.getElementById('form1').innerHTML;
                var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
                document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
                window.print();
                document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
            });

Comment: I tested your code, it works correctly.

Comment: @FarhadMortezapour ok it's work,but when click the first time on the btnPrint it's run his own code and when click second time it's run the code of btnPrintWord

Comment: Please send the code of both event handlers